How to authenticate to an organization's github container registry?
I recently enabled some policies in my github organization's settings, the personal access token policy. However, this had some unintended concequences: my personal account's PATs (classic) were not able anymore to acces the organization's packages. This is probably intended, as I disabled the following setting:

Which disables access to the organization with classic tokens.
However, fine grained tokens do not support github packages yet, but at the same time, the policies only allow to autorise selectively (one by one, not globally) fine grained tokens in the ogranization, and not classic tokens.
Now, I do not want to allow anyone to access the organization with PATs before request, but I still need to authenticate to ghcr.
How could I still access my org's github container registry private images, without allowing access for all classic tokens?
I tried mix and matching different tokens, and tested to verify my assumption was correct.
